# Execute a number of Ansible Plays, one variable list item at a time

Tags: loops, for-loop, ansible, nested-loops

I have an Ansible playbook to automate network changes in an environment. Play one touches Cisco Nexus port channels, needing to move several vlans from one port-channel to another, play 2 touches Cisco ACI by creating the newly required vlans within the required ACI tenant (creates BDs & EPGs)
My playbook & associates vars files, roles, etc. execute this as expected for a **single vlan**, moving between port-channels & doing the ACI creations, however when I have a list of vlan IDs that i need to migrate, I need to not do all the vlan shifts on the Nexus then do all the vlan creations in ACI in a linear method. I need to execute each vlan move & creation as if it was a single vlan, then loop back (for loop, I assume) to the next item (vlan) in the list & do it again.

Var snippet

```
vlan_id:
  - 78
  - 79
  - 80
  - 81
  - 82
```

Task snippet

```
- name: Remove VLAN from port-channel 1 
  nxos_l2_interface:
    name: "{{ item[0] }}"
    mode: "{{ mode }}"
    trunk_vlans: "{{ item[1] }}"
    state: "{{ INTERFACE_REMOVE_state | default('absent') }}"
  with_nested:
  - "{{ INTERFACE_REMOVE_interface }}"
  - "{{ vlan_id }}"

- name: Add VLAN to port-channel 20
  nxos_l2_interface:
    name: "{{ item[0] }}"
    mode: "{{ mode }}"
    trunk_vlans: "{{ item[1] }}"
    state: "{{ INTERFACE_ADD_state | default('present') }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ INTERFACE_ADD_interface }}"
    - "{{ vlan_id }}"
```

When I execute the playbook, task 1 is completed for all vlan_id, then task 2 is completed for all vlan_id.
I want to try & complete task 1 & task 2 for first vlan_id, then complete task1 & task 2 for second vlan_id, then complete task 1 & task 2 for third vlan_id, etc, etc.

Does anyone have a solution I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying.

How about using include in the main part of the with_nested.  Something like:

```
- name: Remove and Add VLAN    
  include add_remove_play.yml name="{{item[0]}}" trunc_vlans="{{item[1]}}"   
  with_nested:
     - "[ {{ INTERFACE_REMOVE_interface }}, {{ INTERFACE_ADD_interface }} ]"
     - "{{ vlan_id }}"
```

and in add_remove_play.yml code the remove and addition serially.  name and trunc_vlans will be set within the call to add_remove_play

Answer (score 0):

After a restless night & getting up & 5am to work on a solution, I have one.
Using include_roles, loop, loop_control & defining inner and outer variable names with loop_var, my solution now works as expected

Playbook snippet

```
---
# Author: Albert Short


###############################################################################
#@ Play1 Legacy environment changes
- hosts: <removed>
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes


#@ The variables required for the main playbook are defined in this variable file
  vars_files:
    - vars/deploy.yml



   tasks:
     - block:
       - name:
         include_role:
           name: combined_roles
         loop: "{{ vlan_id }}"
         loop_control:
           extended: yes
           loop_var: outer_item

...
```

Vars snippet

```
vlan_id:
  - "666"
  - "888"
  - "777"
  - "667"
  - "889"
  - "778"
```

My role contains all the platforms I need to execute against (Cisco Nexus switches, Cisco APIC & Cisco MSC) & the execution of all the tasks are completed on a per VLAN basis, not per task. i.e. all tasks for Nexus, ACI & MSC are completed for VLAN 666, before VLAN 888 is started.

Success!!!